# Insert and update a table at the same time

Tags: java, postgresql, jersey

I have two tables named 'Trending'  and 'Questbank'.

Im trying to insert trending table and update the questbank table at the same time. Following is my code.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO TRENDING ( TOPIC , CATEGORY , QUESTION , ANSWER , PROFILEPIC , TICK , URL ) VALUES( ?, ? , ? , ? , ? , now() , ? )  Returning ID AND UPDATE  QUESTBANK SET wasanswered = 'yes'  WHERE id = ?");
            stmt.setString(1, jsonObj.getString("topic"));
            stmt.setString(2, jsonObj.getString("category"));
            stmt.setString(3, jsonObj.getString("question"));
            stmt.setString(4, jsonObj.getString("answer"));
            stmt.setString(5, jsonObj.getString("profilepic"));
            stmt.setString(6, jsonObj.getString("url"));
            stmt.setInt(7, jsonObj.getInt("id"));
```

But im getting the following error

```
failureorg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near \"SET\"\n  Position: 170"
```

How can I be able to inert a table an update the other table at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using CTEs:

```
WITH i AS (
      INSERT INTO TRENDING ( TOPIC , CATEGORY , QUESTION , ANSWER , PROFILEPIC , TICK , URL )
          VALUES( ?, ? , ? , ? , ? , now() , ? ) 
          Returning ID 
     )
UPDATE QUESTBANK
    SET wasanswered = 'yes' 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT ID FROM i);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have got the following error failureorg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 7, number of columns: 6

Comment: I need to set           '  stmt.setInt(7, jsonObj.getInt("id"));'

Comment: Your need relation between TRENDING and QUESTBANK. In answer relation is id field (TRENDING.id = QUESTBANK.id)

Comment: You can use either CTE as given example here, or use INSERT... ON CONFLICT if have 9.5 or higher. See more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014190/how-to-retrieve-id-of-inserted-row-when-using-upsert-with-with-cluase-in-posgres/39016797#39016797